# How to show that $(I+T/n)^{-1}$ converges strongly to the identity operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $T$ be an m-accretive operator on a Hilbert space. Then how can I show that $(I+T/n)^{-1}$ converges in the strong operator topology to the identity operator $I$?

It seems trickier than I expected...Could anyone help me?

Comment: Remind us, please, what an m-accretive operator is.

Comment: https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/M-accretive-operator

Comment: Do you know that $(I-T)^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} T^k$ if $\| T \| < 1$?

Comment: T is not assumed to be bounded.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Use $\operatorname{Real}\langle Tx,x\rangle \geq 0$ and $T+\lambda I$ is surjective for every $\lambda >0$ to show that $$\|(T+\lambda I)^{-1}\|\leq \frac{1}{\lambda}\quad\forall\; \lambda >0.$$

Comment: I tried to use the inequality but cannot proceed...could you help me more?

Comment: @Keith Take $\lambda =n$....

Comment: That does not work. Because $\lambda$ is not with $I$. That is why I am stuck..... I tried to use functional calculus but that does not work either because $T$ is unbounded......

Comment: What do you mean by $\lambda$ is not with $I$ ?

Comment: I mean that in my question above, the form is $(I+T/n)^{-1}$. Its operator norm is not suppressed by something like $1/n$.

Comment: And the question requires to show strong convergence, not uniform convergence. So I suspect that it does not help to look at the operator norm.

Comment: @Keith You want to show convergence to $I$ not to $0,$ so you don't want the norm to be suppressed by $\frac1n$.

Comment: I think I figured out something... anyway thank you for your help.

Comment: I have searched for some papers and it seems that the strong convergence to the identity operator is guaranteed 'only on the domain of $T$', at this level.

Comment: @Keith: In fact, the strong convergence holds on the entire Hilbert space. Since the discussion seems to be somewhat stuck (here, and for the same - now deleted - question on MathOverflow) I have added another answer where I give some of the details. The main point, though, is really what Sahiba Arora wrote in her answer above.

Answer (score 3):

The main point of the argument has already been pointed out in the answer by Sahiba Arora. Since there seems to be a bit of confusion left, I'll add some of the details here:

Let $X$ be a complex Hilbert space, or more generally, a complex Banach space. Let $T: X \supseteq D(T) \to X$ be an $m$-accreative operator.

1. Then $\lambda \|(\lambda I + T)^{-1}\| \le 1$ for all scalars $\lambda \in (0,\infty)$. This follows, for instance, from [1, Lemma 3.4.2].
2. Now we use that, for each $x \in D(T)$,
   $$
       \Big(\lambda (\lambda I + T)^{-1} - I\Big)x = \Big(\lambda (\lambda I + T)^{-1} - (\lambda I + T)^{-1}(\lambda I + T)\Big)x = -(\lambda I + T)^{-1} T x,
     $$
   and the norm of the later vector is bounded by $\frac{\|Tx\|}{\lambda}$ for each $\lambda \in (0,\infty)$ according to Step 1. This proves that $\lambda(\lambda I + T)^{-1}$ converges to the identity operator strongly on $D(T)$ as $\lambda \to \infty$.
3. Since $\lambda(\lambda +T)^{-1}$ is uniformly norm bounded for $\lambda \in (0,\infty)$ according to Step 1, it follows from a simple approximation argument that $\lambda (\lambda + T)^{-1}$ converges strongly to $I$ even on the closure of $D(T)$ as $\lambda \to \infty$.
4. Now assume in addition that $X$ is reflexive (for instance, a Hilbert space). Then the estimate from Step 1 implies that $T$ is densely defined, see for instance [1, Proposition 3.3.8]. So Step 3) shows that $\lambda (\lambda + T)^{-1}$ converges strongly to $I$ on the whole space $X$ as $\lambda \to \infty$.
5. Finally, note that $(I + T/n)^{-1} = n(n+T)^{-1}$ for each integer $n$, so the assertion you are looking for follows from Step 4 if use set $\lambda = n$ (as indicated by Sahiba Arora).

**Reference:**
[1] Arendt, Batty, Hieber, Neubrander: Vector-Valued Laplace Transforms and Cauchy Problems (second edition, 2011).

**Remark.** The above argument works for single-valued operators. The assertion is false for multi-valued operators.

Comment: I have corrected my misunderstanding and solved the problem with some other helps. (sorry for not updating); but anyway thank you for the answer.